# Numeric UDL operator template

Tags: c++, c++20, user-defined-literals

I'm trying to define what Pablo Halpern [calls](https://youtu.be/0p_RCdoxn5w?t=1809) a numeric UDL operator template. I want it to return a lambda that would count how many characters at the beginning of a `char` array are from the given set.

Here's my test code:

```
template <char... c>
constexpr auto operator ""_cntany() {
  return [](const char* s){
    unsigned n = 0;
    while (((*s==c) || ...)) { ++n; ++s; }
    return n;
  };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return ("test"_cntany)(argv[1]);
}
```

But this doesn't compile with GCC 11.2 (https://godbolt.org/z/TdbKzTMW8).
Here's the error I'm getting:

```
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
<source>:11:15: error: no matching function for call to 'operator""_cntany<"test">()'
  11 |       return ("test"_cntany)(argv[1]);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:2:20: note: candidate: 'template<char ...c> constexpr auto operator""_cntany()'
    2 |     constexpr auto operator ""_cntany() {
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
<source>:2:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:11:15: error: '"test"' is not a valid template argument for type 'char' because string literals can never be used in this context
  11 |       return ("test"_cntany)(argv[1]);
     |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) says

> If the literal operator is a template, it must have an empty parameter list and can have only one template parameter, which must be a non-type template parameter pack with element type char (in which case it is known as a **numeric literal operator template**)

```cpp
template <char...> double operator "" _x();
```

Also see [[over.literal.5]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#5)

i.e. it's numeric-, and not a string literal.

It *can* be used like `123_cntany`.

Note, there is a new C++20 string literal operator template: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278384)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I read this part but missed the point that the prefix can only be a **numeric** literal. Strange that there would be such a limitation.

Answer (score 2):

template user-defined literals need to accept *numeric* values such as `0123_cntany`, so you may need to just use user-defined string-literal:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string_view>

constexpr auto operator ""_cntany(const char* s, std::size_t count) {
  return [sv = std::string_view(s, count)](const char* s){
    unsigned n = 0;
    while (sv.contains(*s)) { ++n; ++s; }
    return n;
  };
}
```

Comment: No need to compute a length when you were given one.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have udl for string with that template format unfortunately.

gcc has an **extension** for that `template <typename Char, Char... c>`

so it would be

```
template <typename Char, Char... c>
constexpr auto operator ""_cntany() {
  return [](const char* s){
    unsigned n = 0;
    while (((*s==c) || ...)) { ++n; ++s; }
    return n;
  };
}
```

but it is not portable as extension.